# Wordpress - location of menu bar items in the files

Tags: wordpress

I want to customise the top menu bar of my wordpress site. By customise I mean modify the actual codes rather than the things we do in the backend interface.

Where can I find these files?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in Apperance -> Editor

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you know in which file the codes for menu bars are normally stored?

Comment: It depends on your chosen themes. When you access Apperance -> Editor, it will show all files which are related to layout. Menu bars usually is stored in sidebar.php ( with my theme )

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your menu bar will be put in header.php file, you can check this file in **your-website**/wp-content/themes/**your-current-theme**/header.php , it was printed out through [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function, if you know about php and wordpress, you can make a cusom Walker class add use it to modify your menu.

Regards

Comment: Thank you too for your answer :)